# Laravel : method is not supported for this route

Tags: php, laravel

the error is : *The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.*
although the website works on localhost but on the server doesnt work ?? any solutions

```
 protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others, $method)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException(
            $others,
            sprintf(
                'The %s method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: %s.',
                $method,
                implode(', ', $others)
            )
        );
    }
```

*layout*

```
@extends('install.layout')

@section('content')
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading text-center">Login Details</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="col-md-12">
            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                       <p>{{ $error }}</p>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif
            <form action="{{ url('install/store_user') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required>             
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>  
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-install">Next</button>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

########################################################################################################################################################
*Web Route*

```
<?php
Route::post('install/store_user', 'Install\InstallController@store_user');
?>
```

*installController*

```
    public function store_user(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);
        
        if ($validator->fails()) {  
                return redirect()->back()
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();          
        }
        
        $name = $request->name;
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = Hash::make($request->password);
        
        Installer::createUser($name, $email, $password);
        
        return redirect('install/system_settings');
    }
```

Comment: This error is thrown when you make a post request for a route that uses a get or get for a route that uses post. Or a request for a route that uses a different method.. can we see your route file and what you are doing

Comment: Which route are we talking about? How do you call/access it? Using a form? Using a link?

Comment: Can you show us ur form and web.php file

Comment: Can you show us ur form and web.php file

Comment: Also what route is giving that issue

Comment: i edit the post can u check again

Answer (score 0):

In your form you may give post method but in route you may assign get method. Please cross check it.

Comment: i change the route from post to get  but nothing happend

Comment: can you give screenshot of your form and route with controller?

Comment: i edit the post can u check it again please

Comment: please add the form also.

Comment: i added it too a

Answer (score 0):

most likely it's because of your URL in the form change your form

from

```
<form action="{{ url('install/store_user') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

to

```
<form action="{{ url('install,store_user') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: it dosent work a

Comment: dose it still gives same error?

Comment: yes it gives same err